# wherein condition with multidimensional array in laravel 8

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-8

I want to use whereIn with a multidimensional array in the Laravel query.

My main requirement is that

there is a multidimensional array just like

```
$language = [ 
   [ 'name' => 'english', 'level' => 'advance', 'lang_id' => '8' ],
   [ 'name' => 'urdu', 'level' => 'fluant', 'lang_id' => '10' ],
   [ 'name' => 'germany', 'level' => 'basic', 'lang_id' => '12' ]
]

$app_lang_arr = [];
$app_lang_arr_level = [];

foreach($language as $lang)
{
    array_push($app_lang_arr, $lang['lang_id']);
    array_push($app_lang_arr_level, $lang['level']);
}

$applicant = $user_arr->whereHas('LanguageSkills', function ($query) use ($app_lang_arr, $app_lang_arr_level) {
                $query->whereIn('language_id', $app_lang_arr)->whereIn('level', $app_lang_arr_level);
            })->where('activate_deactivate', 1)
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

Now my requirement is that

```
 select all from users join language_skills on language_skill.language_id == user.language_id where language_skill.language_id == $lang['lang_id'] AND language_skill.level == $lang['level'];
```

this query is in the loop. I want to use this query in Laravel with whereIn. Or there is any other method to do this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could use `orWhereHas` in loop for your clause

```
foreach($language as $lang)
{
    $user_arr->orWhereHas('LanguageSkills', function ($query) use ($lang) {
                    $query->where('language_id', $lang['lang_id'])
                          ->where('level', $lang['level']);
                });
}                                                                                                                                           

$applicant = $user_arr->where('activate_deactivate', 1)
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```